# How can I select the count of a field multiple times for a different value in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have a database with a table that keeps records with a date of receipt, type, and department.  I want to create a query that shows all records for a specific department, separated horizontally by record type, and aggregated by the month of the date of receipt.  For example:

```
Received | T1 | T2 | T3 |
-------------------------
1        | 11 | 0  | 3  |
2        | 0  | 14 | 30 |
```

And so on.

I successfully generated the first two columns in the query with this code:

```
SELECT Month([receipt date]) AS Received, Count(Type) AS T1
FROM the_table
WHERE Type="T1" AND department="marketing"
GROUP BY Month([receipt date]), Type
```

Now I'm lost on how to get the rest of the type counts into the remaining columns.  Let me know if anything wasn't clear, and thanks in advance for helping!

P.S. There really are only 3 possible "types" and I have to run this in Access 2013.

Comment: If you're using Access, try the query wizard and select cross-tab

Comment: That does not look normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with the cross-tab wizard I got this for an Access query:

```
transform 
    count(*) as CountOfReceipts
select
    Month(x.[Receipt Date]) as Month
from
    the_table x
where
    Department = 'marketing'
group by
    Month(x.[Receipt Date])
pivot
    x.Type;
```

This is specific to access, though. If you're running T-SQL as a pass-through query, the T-SQL syntax for pivot is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` inside a `sum` to count the different types:

```
select
  month([receipt date]) as Received,
  sum(case when Type = 'T1' then 1 else 0 end) as T1,
  sum(case when Type = 'T2' then 1 else 0 end) as T2,
  sum(case when Type = 'T3' then 1 else 0 end) as T3
from
  the_table
where
  department="marketing"
group by
  month([receipt date])
```